# How to find the gateway id when trying to send sms via a dongle using gsm?

Tags: ubuntu, port, apache-axis, gsm, sms-gateway

I tried to send sms using wso2 esb in ubuntu and referred the blog post http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/01/wso2-esb-sending-sms-alerts-for-failures.html. But the problem is how to find the gateway id of the dongle and the com_port in ubuntu. These parameters are needed to be configured in the axis2.xml.

```
<transportsender name="sms" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.sms.SMSSender">
<parameter name="smsImplClass">org.apache.axis2.transport.sms.gsm.GSMImplManager</parameter>
<parameter name="com_port">/dev/ttyUSB0</parameter>
<parameter name="gateway_id">modem.ttyUSB0</parameter>
<parameter name="baud_rate">115200</parameter>
<parameter name="manufacturer">HUAWEI</parameter>
<parameter name="model">E220</parameter>
</transportsender>
```

Above given values are in that blog post and I want to enter my dongle configuration values. And I found the com_port as "/dev/ttyUSB4" but not sure. My OS is ubuntu.

Comment: Ask your operator for the SMS gateway address.  Not sure about the port, I only know how to find it in Windows.  Incidentally, please specify in your question which OS you're using.

Comment: Are u meaning that the gateway address is just the ISP dependent and ISP specific? So isn't there a method to find the gateway by our computer without referring to the operator(ISP) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think finally I found the answer myself. I could find the com port via terminal by the command,(as super user)

```
wvdialconf
```

It gives the possible ports from which the dongle could be accessed, as well the baud_rate and the manufacturer too. (manufaturer seems not useful anyhow). The wvdial would give the com_port as

```
/dev/ttyUSB3
```

or

`/dev/ttyUSB0` 
or something in that pattern.
And the gateway_id is in the pattern as I mentioned in the question which was in the blog post. 
If the com_port was /dev/ttyUSB0 the gateway id is

```
modem.ttyUSB0
```

It worked for me.